# MAX between 2 variables in a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

I need to get the max value between 2 variables in a SPARQL query, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
    WHERE{
        ......
        ?person :age ?age .
        ?info :retirementAge ?retirementAge .

        BIND(MAX(?age, ?retirementAge) AS $maxBetweenAgeAndRetirementAge)

        ?maxBetweenAgeAndRetirementAge.....
    }
```

But `MAX(?age, ?retirementAge)` is invalid (I think?). SPARQL seems to allow arithmetic operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` so I'm wondering what I need to do to get it to work.

Comment: MAX is an aggregate function, so that's the wrong way. SPARQL has support for some numeric functions, but unfortunately not max. See https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-numerics

Comment: You could use IF THEN ELSE instead, e.g. `BIND(IF(?age < ?retirement, ?retirement, ?age) as ?maxBetweenAgeAndRetirementAge)`

Comment: @AKSW Will the IF() definitely work? If so, can you put it as an answer?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it's at least part of SPARQL 1.1 standard. I thought you'd run it on your example?

Comment: I don't have the data to test against yet but I will